# Oracle streams_pool_size

Tags: oracle, performance, parameters, instance, queueing

Environment:
Oracle 12.2 64-bit EE under Linux.

**SGA_TARGET** and **STREAMS_POOL_SIZE** are both equal to 0.

**SGA_MAX_SIZE** = 180G.

If I don't trust amount of memory, automatically allocated by Oracle internal system process, what value can I confidently assign manually to
**STREAMS_POOL_SIZE** parameter without fear for database performance?

Comment: This will get better attention is you move to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ - a DBA forum

Comment: Why do you not trust oracle to be smart enough to do the right thing?  I'd just let it go, and if you have a _real, demonstrated_ performance issue _that can definitively be tracked to memory allocation_  then you can respond accordingly.  Since you are on linux, the one thing I would do proactively is implement HUGEPAGES at the OS level. (look it up).

Comment: I do not trust because of this article:https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/dont-let-the-streams-pool-fool-you.html

Comment: Hmm... STREAMS_POOL_SIZE is 1Gb.  Instead of investigating v$parameter I posted the value of **dbms_aqadm.get_min_streams_pool function**.